# Why must i change my DB_PORT to 33060 to run migration and then have to change it back to 3306? Laravel6

Tags: mysql-workbench, laravel-6

i get this error when i try to do a migration with DB_PORT=3306

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

So i have to change the DB_PORT to `DB_PORT=33060`

Then i get this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 1 limit 1)
```

when i try to load a view with this code

```html
<div>
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        {{$user}}
                        @endforeach
                </div>
```

and have to change my port back to 
`DB_PORT=3306` for it to function properly.

I'm using MySQL Workbench and this is a huge problem, as I started dealing with Queues/Notifications and in order to run a command like
`php artisan migrate` or `php artisan queue:work` i have to go into my .env and change my port in order for the queue to process and then i have to change the port back in order to load a view WITHOUT getting a error if the view uses any variables/data passed from a controller.

Comment: What makes you think a change of the port is required?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that while changing the DB_PORT did allow me to run commands like migrate and queue:work, I never realized my PHPStorm terminal wasn't actually working inside of my vagrant environment. I needed to be ssh'd into the VM while running the commands.